# Dynatrace AWS access key verification domains (url/ip)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, dynatrace, corporate-policy

We have implemented Dynatrace and we need to add our AWS account to pull CloudWatch logs.

The problem: We have a corporate proxy and firewall which is super locked down and seems to block whichever requests Dynatrace is trying to make to AWS to authenticate with the key and secret.

The infra guys has *allowed* a bunch of AWS domains per region to read CloudWatch logs, but we still can't authenticate (see image below).

I have set up a Dynatrace security gateway in AWS which our local gateways are able to access. We are successfully getting logs form OneAgents through the SGW. The problem is getting the CloudWatch logs/integration going.

The error in the image below leads me to believe that Dynatrace is not able to communicate to the AWS auth servers at all.

Any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

- I'm just a dev
- We are not allowed to open the amazon domain.

`#corporate-devlife`

Comment: Can you find anything from the browser dev tools?  An "unknown error" sounds like a problem someone didn't anticipate, so the vendor should be able to improve this with better diagnostics.

Comment: I did check the console - the client side just posts to the dynatrace server which then tries to do the auth.
I think I might suggest they run wireshark or something to inspect the server's traffic which may reveal an IP or domain.

Comment: *"the dynatrace server"*... is this a server on your side, inside your network, or is it the vendor's web server you are referring to, here?

Comment: The main server is on-prem in our data center. The vendor actually tested our AWS credentials from their servers and said it worked fine. Somewhere in our DC something is blocking it, and I do not know what to tell the infra gays to open.

Comment: It's a bit old but did you find a solution ? 
I'm having the same issue